Regex Derivative DFA: This Should Work, But It's Breaking in Unexpected Ways
I’m working on a DFA-based lexer using regex derivatives for tokenizing lexemes. I've built a setup that, theoretically, should handle regex simplification and DFA transitions accurately. For the most part, it’s going smoothly... until I hit a few cases where things just don’t line up. It’s as if some hidden edge cases are mocking me.
The logic looks solid (following Brzozowski’s derivative theory, implementing simplifications, transition logic, etc.), and I've documented the whole derivation history, so it’s easy to trace what's going on. But every now and then, the output goes off-script, extra states pop up, simplifications don’t fully reduce, or transitions don't quite behave as expected.
I’m not looking for spoon-fed answers here. Just curious if any regex or DFA enthusiasts might spot what I’m missing or enjoy the challenge of testing it out. It’s kind of a fascinating puzzle, really. Everything should be right, but some cases just slip through.
The code’s here: GitHub
Core logic for calculating regex derivatives and simplifications:
public class RegexDerivativeCalculator
{
    /* ... */

    public IRegexNode Derive(IRegexNode node, char c)
    {
        IRegexNode derivative;

        switch (node.Type)
        {
            // ...
        }

        /* add history for debugging */
        History.AddDerivative(node, c, derivative);

        /* simplify the derivative before returning it */
        return Simplify(derivative);
    }

    public IRegexNode Simplify(IRegexNode node)
    {
        IRegexNode simplified;

        switch (node.Type)
        {
            // ...
        }

        /* if the simplified node is the same as the original node, we don't need to add it to the history */
        if (!simplified.Equals(node))
        {
            History.AddSimplification(node, simplified);
        }

        return simplified;
    }

    /* derivative calculation */

    private IRegexNode DeriveEpsilonNode(EpsilonNode node, char c)
    {
        return new EmptySetNode();
    }

    private IRegexNode DeriveEmptySetNode(EmptySetNode node, char c)
    {
        return new EmptySetNode();
    }

    private IRegexNode DeriveLiteralNode(LiteralNode node, char c)
    {
        return c == node.Literal
            ? new EpsilonNode()
            : new EmptySetNode()
            ;
    }

    private IRegexNode DeriveUnionNode(UnionNode node, char c)
    {
        var leftDerivative = Derive(node.Left, c);
        var rightDerivative = Derive(node.Right, c);

        return new UnionNode(leftDerivative, rightDerivative);
    }

    private IRegexNode DeriveConcatenationNode(ConcatenationNode node, char c)
    {
        var left = node.Left;
        var right = node.Right;
        var leftDerivative = Derive(left, c);
        var rightDerivative = Derive(right, c);

        if (left.ContainsEpsilon)
        {
            return new UnionNode(
                new ConcatenationNode(leftDerivative, right),
                rightDerivative
            );
        }
        else
        {
            return new ConcatenationNode(leftDerivative, right);
        }
    }

    private IRegexNode DeriveStarNode(StarNode node, char c)
    {
        var child = node.Child;
        var derivative = Derive(child, c);

        if (derivative.IsEmptySet())
        {
            return new EmptySetNode();
        }

        return new ConcatenationNode(derivative, new StarNode(child));
    }

    /* simplification */

    private IRegexNode SimplifyEpsilonNode(EpsilonNode node)
    {
        return node;
    }

    private IRegexNode SimplifyEmptySetNode(EmptySetNode node)
    {
        return node;
    }

    private IRegexNode SimplifyLiteralNode(LiteralNode node)
    {
        return node;
    }

    private IRegexNode SimplifyUnionNode(UnionNode node)
    {
        var left = node.Left;
        var right = node.Right;
        var simplifiedLeft = Simplify(left);
        var simplifiedRight = Simplify(right);

        if (simplifiedLeft.IsEmptySet())
        {
            return simplifiedRight;
        }
        if (simplifiedRight.IsEmptySet())
        {
            return simplifiedLeft;
        }

        if (left.IsEpsilon() && simplifiedRight.ContainsEpsilon)
        {
            return simplifiedRight;
        }
        if (right.IsEpsilon() && simplifiedLeft.ContainsEpsilon)
        {
            return simplifiedLeft;
        }

        // Avoid duplicate terms (R ∪ R = R)
        if (simplifiedLeft.Equals(simplifiedRight))
        {
            return simplifiedLeft;
        }

        return new UnionNode(simplifiedLeft, simplifiedRight);
    }

    private IRegexNode SimplifyConcatenationNode(ConcatenationNode node)
    {
        var left = node.Left;
        var right = node.Right;
        var simplifiedLeft = Simplify(left);
        var simplifiedRight = Simplify(right);

        // Concatenation with Empty Set (∅ ∘ R or R ∘ ∅ = ∅)
        if (simplifiedLeft.IsEmptySet() || simplifiedRight.IsEmptySet())
        {
            return new EmptySetNode();
        }

        // Concatenation with Epsilon (ε ∘ R = R and R ∘ ε = R)
        if (simplifiedLeft.IsEpsilon())
        {
            return simplifiedRight;
        }
        if (simplifiedRight.IsEpsilon())
        {
            return simplifiedLeft;
        }

        return new ConcatenationNode(simplifiedLeft, simplifiedRight);
    }

    private IRegexNode SimplifyStarNode(StarNode node)
    {
        var simplifiedChild = Simplify(node.Child);

        // Star of Empty Set (∅*) simplifies to Epsilon (ε)
        if (simplifiedChild.IsEmptySet())
        {
            return new EpsilonNode();
        }

        // Star of Epsilon (ε*) simplifies to Epsilon (ε)
        if (simplifiedChild.IsEpsilon())
        {
            return new EpsilonNode();
        }

        // Avoid redundant nested stars (if the child is already a star, return the simplified child)
        if (simplifiedChild.IsStar())
        {
            return simplifiedChild;
        }

        return new StarNode(simplifiedChild);
    }

}

Update 1:
Upon further inspection, I found that a simplification step was removing critical accepting states in the DFA. The issue occurred in cases like a|a(b)*, where, after consuming 'a', the regex would derive to ε|(b)*. For any character other than 'b', the regex should still accept because it produces ε, and the derivative results in an empty set. If 'b' is consumed, the derivative proceeds to (b)*.
The simplification was collapsing ε|(b)* directly to (b)*, assuming that ε was already implied in the star of 'b'. However, this was incorrect, as the state with ε is essential to represent the point where the lexeme 'a' can be recognized. The fix was to avoid this simplification in such cases, thereby preserving necessary accepting states.
/*
 * This simplification has been removed because it would eliminate accepting branches.
 * For example, `a|a(b)*` becomes `ε|(b)*` after consuming 'a', and if 'b' is not seen,
 * the regex should still accept.
 */
if (left.IsEpsilon() && simplifiedRight.ContainsEpsilon)
{
    // return simplifiedRight
    //     .PropagateLexeme(node);
}

/*
 * This simplification has been removed because it would eliminate accepting branches.
 * For example, `a(b)*|a` becomes `(b)*|ε` after consuming 'a', and if 'b' is not seen,
 * the regex should still accept.
 */
if (right.IsEpsilon() && simplifiedLeft.ContainsEpsilon)
{
    // return simplifiedLeft
    //     .PropagateLexeme(node);
}


Have you stepped through the code with a debugger, setting breakpoints, inspecting variables, in order to spot the first statement where things go different from what you expected? Can you provide the main code (in your post) with which the issue can be reproduced? Make sure to focus on one issue only, otherwise this question will be closed as too broad.

@trincot Thanks for the suggestion! I’ve actually got a solid debugging setup that logs the entire history of derivations and simplifications. I’m going through it carefully, but due to the complexity of the algorithm, I haven’t pinpointed the exact issue yet. I’ll keep digging and update with more details as soon as I have them.

There is no need to make your post with update sections. Just edit your question to present that latest situation only, with the question you have on that situation, as otherwise new visitors will have to read through a history that is no longer relevant.
